# Date formatting sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqlplus

I have this sql script:

```
select 'LASTBUSDATE='|| to_char(max(calen_dt),'mmdd') LBD
from put_calen
where calen_dt < (select calen_dt from put_calen where ca_run_dt_ind = 'Y')
and business_day_ind = 'Y';
exit;
```

How can I modify this so I will get first business day and last business day of previous month like `2-1-2011` and `2-28-2011`

Please help. Don't know whats going on in here.

Comment: How are you defining "business day"?

Comment: And, for that matter, how are your defining "business month"? For example, at my place of annoy^H^H^H^H^Hemployment our fiscal months do not match the usual calendar, e.g. our fiscal month #3 this year begins on April 2. Just to make it fun, our RETAIL calendar also does not match the the usual calendar AND IN ADDITION it doesn't match the fiscal calendar (retail month #3, for example, began this year on March 27). So we're dealing with a lot of stuff here.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing on your table structure from your column names here, but does the following return what you want?

```
select min(calen_dt) as first_business_day
      ,max(calen_dt) as last_business_day
  from put_calen
 where calen_dt >= trunc(sysdate,'MM') - interval '1' month
   and calen_dt <= trunc(sysdate,'MM') - interval '1' day
   and business_day_ind = 'Y';
```

If sysdate = "2011-03-31 19:14:32", then `trunc(sysdate,'MM')` would return "2011-03-01 00:00:00"; basically the date truncated to month.

You wanted the first and last business day in previous month, so I subtracted 1 month to arrive at the first of the previous month, and 1 day to arrive at the last day of the previous month. The filter `business_day_ind = 'Y'` makes sure that only business days are consider for the min/max.

Let me know how it works, or if I missunderstood your question and/or table structure :)